# Switch Statement gives Incompatible Types error

Tags: java, switch-statement

I am trying to compile and I get this error:

```
enigma/Rotor.java:30: incompatible types found : java.lang.String required: int     switch(name){
1 error
```

Why am I getting this error? How do I fix it? It's in the package and I can't seem to figure it out. Here's the code:

```
String label;

Rotor(){;}

Rotor(String name){
  switch(name){
    case "B":
      conversion_chart = B;
      break;
    case "C":
      conversion_chart = C;
      break;
    case "I":
      conversion_chart=I;
      notch = NOTCH[0];
      break;
    case "II":
      conversion_chart=II;
      notch = NOTCH[1];
      break;
    case "III":
      conversion_chart=III;
      notch = NOTCH[2];
      break;
    case "IV":
      conversion_chart=IV;
      notch = NOTCH[3];
      break;
    case "V":
      conversion_chart=V;
      notch = NOTCH[4];
      break;
    case "VI":
      conversion_chart=VI;
      notch = NOTCH[5];
      break;
    case "VII":
      notch = NOTCH[6];
      conversion_chart=VII;
      break;
    case "VIII":
      notch = NOTCH[7];
      conversion_chart=VIII;
      break;
  }
  label = name;
  position = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

```
switch(name)
```

`switch` statement with String  is supported from Java7 onwards only.

I guess the compiler version you are using is less than Java7

Options:

1. You need to either upgrade to Java7
2. Change switch statement to `if/else`
3. Use `int` in switch instead of `String`

Comment: You need to upgrade your java to Java7

Comment: And if this still fails, it could be your IDE. For intelliJ, go to `File > Project Structure > Project > Project Language Level` and set to 7 and above

Answer (score 6):

If you are using maven project then simply you can add following piece of code to ypur pom.xml and resolve your problem :

```
 <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: Looks like Maven stuck in medieval times. I had never ever thought that such obvious thing like standard java API should be enabled explicitly by adding some lines in maven pom file. It works tho, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

**switch** accepts a **String from java 7**. **prior to java 7** only **int compatible types (short,byte,int, char)** can be passed as switch arguments

Comment: I'm really sorry about that.  I have been trying to remove this downvote and it tells me I'm not allowed to change my vote.  It was an accidental downvote, is there an undo?

Comment: @krico i have just edited my post, you can now revert your downvote .. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using maven then change build in pom as following else change JDK version as 1.8+

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot switch over a String instance, only int (and byte/char/short, but not long/double), unless you have Java7+. Your best option now is to change to if else statements, like so:

```
if("B".equals(string)) {
    //handle string being "B"
} else if("C".equals(string)) {
    //handle string being "C"
} else ...
```

For more info on switching, see the Oracle [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html). They mention the Java7 String functionality:

> In Java SE 7 and later, you can use a String object in the switch statement's expression.

Comment: @user1514362 What do you mean? I gave you an example which doesn't use a switch statement but perfoms the same thing. Isn't this what you want? You must remove your switch statement to make it work

Answer (score -1):

In Java, you can only do a switch on byte, char, short, or int, and not a String.

Comment: Unless you are using Java 7 or newer - see other answers.